# Comparando Strings usando ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Preciso que na repetição ele identifique os Strings iguais, sei que preciso usar o .equals(), porém está dando erro, como se a variável x estivesse verificando mais valor que existem no ArrayList, mas tem como condição que o x seja menor que o "dados.size()" (que é o tamanho do meu vetor).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> dados= new ArrayList<String>();

        //OBS. Primeiramente inserir os dados, futuramente
        //ler arquivos txt
        dados.add("Dado 2");
        dados.add("Dado 1");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        Collections.sort(dados);  
        //while(dados.contains(dados)){
          //  System.out.println("deu certo");
        //}       
        //for (String x : dados){
        //    System.out.println(x);
        //    if (x.contains(x))
       // }     
        int i;
        int contador = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int tamanho = dados.size();
        for (i = 0; i<tamanho; i++){        
            System.out.println(dados.get(i));
                if (x<dados.size() && dados.get(i).equals(dados.get(++x))){
                System.out.println("entrou no contador");
                contador++;
                }              
        } 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Erro gerado do codigo:

[image: Erro gerado do código]

> ```
> [ERRO]
> run:
> Dado 1
> Dado 2
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
> Dado 3
> entrou no contador
> Dado 3
> entrou no contador
> Dado 3
>     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>     at projetoic.main.main(main.java:118)
> C:\Users\lsilv\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 5 segundos)
> ```

Comment: A título de comentário, seria melhor você colocar o código na pergunta ao invés de imagem pra facilitar a quem for te ajudar ;)

Comment: Seu for precisa ser **`< tamanho`** e não **`<= tamanho`**.

Comment: Coloca o código em forma de texto, em forma de imagem atrapalha testar,.

Comment: Editei e adicionei o código do projeto, fiz as devidas correções enviadas aqui, porém o erro persiste..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

> `dados.get(++x)`

`++x` é diferente de `x++`:

- **Pós Incremento** (`x++`): o pós incremento acontece depois que a expressão atual terminar. Por exemplo: assumindo que `x = 1`, se você fizer `dados.get(x++)` você terá o item do index `1` e depois que esse item for retornado (ou melhor, depois que toda a expressão for finalizada), aí sim o `x` recebe um incremento e passa a ter o valor `2`. Resumidamente, em termos literais o que acontece é: `dados.get(1)`
- **Pré Incremento** (`++x`): o pré incremento acontece antes da expressão terminar. Por exemplo: assumindo que `x = 1`, se você fizer `dados.get(++x)` primeiro a variável `x` receberá um incremento, alterando o valor dela para `2` e só depois disso a expressão anterior continuará, fazendo com que você pegue o index `2` da lista, e não o `1`.  Resumidamente, em termos literais o que acontece é: `dados.get(2)`.

---

Dessa forma, mesmo que você faça a validação no `if`, ao usar o operador como pré incremento, você tentará buscar uma posição inexistente na sua lista.

Troque para `dados.get(x++)` e vai funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito, era esse o erro que estava procurando, eu mudei a estrutura mas mantive o incremento antes do x, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar os Streams do java para contar dessa forma:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("a");
list.add("a");
list.add("a");

Map<String, Long> counted = list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

O código acima faz uma stream e agrupa as palavras iguais `e -> e` e contando as ocorrências `Collectors.counting()`. Dessa forma o map resultante fica < Palavra, Ocorrências>

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
{a=4, b=2, c=2, d=1}
```

Veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/3P954Q)

Quanto ao seu código é como já falaram, prestar atenção na condição do laço. (Ela é i < tamanho)

Answer (score 2):

1 - O índice i vai de 0 a tamanho-1: dados[0]=="Dado 1"... dados[4]="Dado 3" (o último Dado 3). Portanto a condição do for tem que ser 'i < tamanho'.

2 - A condição 'x<dados.size()' está depois de se tentar pegar o valor com 'dados.get(++x)' assim ela não impede que se tente pegar um valor já fora dos limites do array.

3 - Qual a resposta que você espera? Porque arrumando as condições acima a saída seria 2.

4 - Reforço o comentário do rLinhares, não coloque uma imagem do código/erro e sim copie e cole o texto em si, para que quem for te ajudar possa aproveitar o texto. Para isso use o ícone de formatação para código: o ícone '{}' que aparece na parte de cima da caixa onde você digita sua pergunta/resposta aqui no stack.
Fica assim:

```
ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();
dados.add("Dado 2");
dados.add("Dado 1");
```

Comment: Apliquei as correções que me sugeriu, porém o erro continua :/

Comment: Cola o código e o erro aqui para tentarmos ver o que pode ser.

Comment: Código postado :)

Comment: Coloque o incremento na comparação, e que seja o pré incremento. Caso contrário você está comparando que x é menor que o tamanho da lista, mas na hora de pegar o item você usa índice (x que você comparou)+1. Então ficaria 'if ++x<dados.size() && ... equals(dados.get(x))

Comment: Eu não consigo comentar na resposta do Igor Venturelli: pode ser daquele jeito também, com pós incremento no x do equals, só lembrar que nesse caso x teria que iniciar em 1.

Comment: Uma última dica, tente simular o programa com papel e caneta, colocando os valores de i, x, dados.get(i), dados.get(x) em cada loop. Vai ajudar bastante a entender o que está acotecendo ;-)

Comment: Muito obrigado Mari, segui o comentário do Igor e deu tudo certo já!!

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando acessar o index 5 de um array que vai até 4 (0,1,2,3,4).